# How to implement Hyperledger composer rest api by own with nodejs?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I am developing application using hyperledger composer.My role is as a developer and I am working on chan code as well as rest api.
As framework provides rest server with automatically gnerated API.
Is it possible to develop api in nodejs by own?
My aim is to take full control on restapi server so i no need to implement more api for other things in application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can develop your own API using the [Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.3/index.html).

Comment: I am asking about rest api server. I want full controlover rest api code.

Comment: You asked about developing your own API. This is what you can use the SDK for. If this is not what you want, maybe you could clarify what it is you're actually asking?

Comment: I have developed chain code and i do not want to generate api through composer-rest-server. I need to create own node application to create api , so i can use same aaplication for my web application also.

Comment: I've answered the question. Use the SDK. I don't know what else I can say. If you have a specific question about how to use the SDK, please post another question.